# What do the folders under Cygwin represent?

Tags: cygwin

Here is a screenshot of what I can see inside my Cygwin directory:

[image]

I want to find out what each of these folders mean and represent. Also, what do the files inside these do. I only know of .bashrc file so far that can be used to customize how cygwin works but not the rest.

What resource can I use to find the details of this?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_Hierarchy_Standard

Comment: thanks but the link does not contain things about the files e.g .bashrc file

Comment: As mentioned by @choroba, the Cygwin folder has the same structure expected by a vanilla Unix system as root folder. `Cygdrive` has a special functionality https://cygwin.com/faq.html#faq.using.accessing-drives

Comment: `.bashrc` is stored under `/home/your_username` as your additional personal setting for `bash` shell. The document explains `/home`

Answer (score 0):

Cygwin uses the same folder structure of *nix systems:

- `bin` (*Binaries*): Executable programs for all users.
- `cygdrive`: Points to your local windows drives (e.g. `/cygdrive/c` points to `C:\`)
- `dev` (*Devices*): The files in this folder are not content from the disk. They actually represent devices (disks, usb, audio,
  cam, terminal output/input, etc). When you interact with these "files", you are interacting with devices.
- `etc` (*Editable Text Configuration*): Machine-specific configuration files.
- `home`: Home directories for system users specific configuration files, documents, personal stuff, etc.
- `lib` (*Libraries*): Shared libraries (including libraries used by binaries from `/bin` and `/sbin`).
- `sbin` (*System Binaries*): Binaries to configure and manipulate the operating system.
- `tmp` (*Temporary*): Space reserved for short-lived files and folders.
- `usr` (*Unix System Resources*): Shared and read-only resources and programs (not operating system level).
- `var`: Variable data produced by the system that is not exclusive to a particular user. Most notably log files.

Cygwin will create a unix-like system inside your windows environment, as if it was in a box. So notice that the configuration files, logs, system binaries and others are related to this sandboxed unix-like environment, and not to your Windows Operating System.

Additional resources about the folders:

- https://linux-training.be/funhtml/ch11.html
- You may also google for things related to *"linux directory structure"* or *"linux filesystem hierarchy"*